# SEO implications with URL rewriting

Tags: seo, url-rewriting

We server our content in http://www.domain.com/folder which is bookmarked by user and has to stay that way.

Out next iteration will be http://www.domain.com/folder2.

We intend to use url rewriting to keep the url http://www.domain.com/folder, but serve the content from http://www.domain.com/folder2.

What are the SEO implication, will Google penalize us?

Answer (score 1):

A user agent makes a request to a URI and gets a response. The End.

What happens behind the scenes is invisible and irrelevant to the client.

Comment: Very swift answer, my CEO will like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will not get a penalty for this because Google (or any other agent/user) wont know it is a rewrite rule.
Just make sure if you change your content to be carefull with all the SEO stuff (title, keywords, alt, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Will http://www.domain.com/folder2 also be accessible and serve the same content as http://www.domain.com/folder? If so, then you would likely pick up a Google penalty if both urls are indexed serving the same content.

Comment: http://www.domain.com/folder2 is evolved content from http://www.domain.com/folder. 

http://www.domain.com/folder2 is the only content to be served via url http://www.domain.com/folder

Comment: What would happen if I entered the url domain.com/folder2 in a browser? Would it redirect me back your domain.com/folder?

Comment: You would get a 404 since domain.com/folder2 isn't officially served.

We would serve the content in domain.com/folder2 under the url domain.com/folder